# Draw vertical lines as nodes along a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I created the following Tikzpicutre:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (Borrow) at (-3, 9) {$b < 0$};
    \node (Lend) at (3, 9) {$b > 0$};
    \node (Top) at (0, 11) {$i^{dw}$};
    \node (Bottom) at (0, 7) {$i^m$};
    \draw[|-|] (Top) -- (Bottom) node[pos =0.6, right] (Funds) {$i^{ff}, \Lambda$}
    node[pos =0.2, right] (AverageBorrowing) {$\chi^{-}$}
    node[pos =0.8, right] (AverageLending) {$\chi^{+}$};
    \draw[->] (Borrow) -- (Top) node[pos = 0.66, above] (DW)  {$1-\varphi^{-}$};
    \draw[->] (Borrow) -- (Funds) node[pos = 0.66, above] (BFunds)  {$\varphi^{-}$};
    \draw[->] (Lend) -- (Bottom) node[pos = 0.3, below] (Overnight)  {$1-\varphi^{+}$};
     \draw[->] (Lend) -- (Funds) node[pos = 0.3, above] (LFunds)  {$\varphi^{+}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I created three nodes along the vertical line between the top (annotated i^dw) and the bottom (annotated i^m). I would like to change two elements of the picture:

- Instead of aligning the text for these nodes at the right,  I would like to align it at the north-east (top-right).
- There should be a horizontal line crossing the line between the Top and the Bottom nodes at each of the three nodes. The arrows to the middle node (Funds) should point to the vertical line instead of the text.

Can somebody kindly suggest a way to implement these two changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understood all your descriptions right. I think you want the node text attached to the vertical line to be aligned top-right. That can be done using `anchor=south west`. But then you want to use the positioning on the line to attach the arrows and a vertical line, so I think it is easier to use as small node as possible and use `label` ti set the text outside it. Then I end with something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (Borrow) at (-3, 9) {$b < 0$};
    \node (Lend) at (3, 9) {$b > 0$};
    \node (Top) at (0, 11) {$i^{dw}$};
    \node (Bottom) at (0, 7) {$i^m$};
    \draw[|-|] (Top) -- (Bottom) node[pos =0.6,label=45:{$i^{ff},\Lambda$},inner sep=0pt] (Funds) {}
    node[pos =0.2,inner sep=0pt,label=45:{$\chi^{-}$}] (AverageBorrowing) {}
    node[pos =0.8,inner sep=0pt,label=45:{$\chi^{+}$}] (AverageLending) {};
    \draw[->] (Borrow) -- (Top) node[pos = 0.66, above] (DW)  {$1-\varphi^{-}$};
    \draw[->] (Borrow) -- (Funds.center) node[pos = 0.66, above] (BFunds)  {$\varphi^{-}$};
    \draw[->] (Lend) -- (Bottom) node[pos = 0.3, below] (Overnight)  {$1-\varphi^{+}$};
    \draw[->] (Lend) -- (Funds.center) node[pos = 0.3, above] (LFunds)  {$\varphi^{+}$};
    %%
    \draw[dashed, red] ([xshift=-1cm]AverageBorrowing.center) -- +(2cm,0cm);
    \draw[dashed, red] ([xshift=-1cm]Funds.center) -- +(2cm,0cm);
    \draw[dashed, red] ([xshift=-1cm]AverageLending.center) -- +(2cm,0cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]